# Cookie SameSite with a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is a chrome extension affected by SameSite cookie policy?
I use method chrome.cookies.get to retrieve a cookie from a website open in a tab.
What happens if this cookie has a SameSite attribute set to strict?

Thank you

Comment: Extensions aren't sites, they are part of the browser side of things so they can see [all types of cookies](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#type-SameSiteStatus).

Comment: Ok thank you it's nice. I tried with Chrome Canary 81 and there is no effect, I still can access to all cookies so you are right.

Answer (score 2):

From https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug#TOC-Testing-Chrome-extensions

> Chrome extensions must also abide by the new SameSite cookie behavior. Extension pages, which have a `chrome-extension://` scheme URL, are generally considered cross-site to any web page (`https://` or `http://`). There are certain scenarios where an exception is made (this is accurate as of Chrome 80, but behavior may change in the future):
>
> If an extension page initiates a request to a web URL, the request is considered same-site if the extension has host permission for the requested URL in the extension’s manifest. This could happen, for example, if an extension page has an iframe embedding a site that the extension has host permission for.
>
> If the top level frame (i.e. the site shown in the URL bar) is an extension page, and the extension has host permission for the requested URL, and the requested URL and the initiator of the request are same-site to each other, and the extension has host permission for the initiator origin, then the request is considered same-site. For example, this could happen if an extension has host permission for “`*://*.site.example/`”, and an extension page loads `a.site.example` in an `iframe`, which then navigates to `b.site.example`.
>
> The `chrome.cookies` API is able to read and set any kind of cookie, including SameSite cookies. However, a web page embedded in an extension page is considered to be in a third party context for the purposes of document.cookie (JavaScript) accesses. For content scripts, the behavior of SameSite cookies is exactly the same as if the request were initiated from the page on which the content script is running.

Answer (score 1):

SameSite will not impact access to a cookie.

The cookie SameSite value only affects the browsers behaviour on request it makes outbound, whether on not to include the cookie on the request being made.

For SameSite strict - the browser will only include the a cookie from the same domain. So if your browser location is currently on myDomain.com and you make a request to any path still on MyDomain.com the cookie will be included with the request. But if you make a cross site request (request from myDomain.com to someOtherSite.com) the browser will not include any myDomain.com cookies that are set as strict or lax.

This link is quite detailed on the cookie same site subject if you're interested.
https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/

Comment: This is not the answer to OPs question. He wanted to know SameSite behaviour, in context of a browser extension, not browser.